# How to frame an outlet between studs

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I’m remodeling an old kitchen. Drywall is removed. I’d like to add a receptacle in a spot between studs. I suppose I could add a stud but it is a 10’ ceiling and would hate to waste a 2x4 just for the receptacle (not to mention the cost of lumber now!!!)

Maybe I’m overthinking it! Any suggestions on how to frame it. Would it be just a simple as two cross beams and a horizontal mini stud between them?

I looked for code requirements for mounting receptacles but could not find anything specific. I’m in Ontario Canada if there are code considerations.

Thanks!

Comment: How far from the stud?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple 2x6 horizontally across the stud bay is all that is needed,
2 screws  from the back of the box into the 2x6.

Remember if in the center and no clamps NMB needs to be stapled within 8”

Make sure to set the back cross beam or horizontal box hanger so your box will protrude ~1/2” beyond the face of the stud I have seen DIY’s forget this step and the inspector flagged them on the cover inspection.

They did not know what to do but a box extension in all of there locations worked fine.  It was good they called a 1$ Fix per box (I fixed the big stuff he flagged).
It can be done with a single 2x4 but they are not as solid as a 2x6.

Comment: Maybe have it protrude more than 1/2"  if in a kitchen and will be tiling over drywall.+1

Comment: If you're going with back mounting, especially with NMD design boxes, also make sure you drill any necessary holes so you can drive any ground or wire holder screws.

Comment: Thanks Ed. I think I’ll go with this approach. Yep, will consider the drywall as well as the tiling .

Comment: I prefer the adjustable depth boxes for places where tile will be added. It has a screw that moves the  box in or out so you place it perfectly after the tile is in place. - https://www.lowes.com/pd/CARLON-1-Gang-Blue-Plastic-New-Work-Standard-Adjustable-Wall-Electrical-Box/3497486

Comment: This one, in your situation, may be better as it would only require you to put a cross brace across two studs.   -  https://www.lowes.com/pd/CARLON-1-Gang-Blue-Plastic-New-Work-Standard-Adjustable-Wall-Electrical-Box/4411967

Answer (score 1):

Your idea for a "*simple as two cross beams and a horizontal mini stud between them?*" will work.

You could use an old work box. It is designed to be used to install a box in existing drywall where no stud is available to attach too.

[Here is tutorial](https://www.thespruce.com/install-old-work-electrical-box-1824655).

In your case you would install your wire, staple it and leave enough so you can pull it out and through the hole you will be cutting. Then install your drywall. Cut the hole for your old work box, pull the wire through and then through the tabbed hole in the back of the box. Install the box in the drywall hole and tighten  the tabs.

> The screw that goes into the retention tab on the box may sometimes be
> very tight when the box comes from the manufacturer. This may require
> you to put considerable pressure against the wall when you turn the
> screw, which may damage the wall.

Once you have the box secure then you install the outlet or switch and plate.

Here is a [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t8-SREflid8).

Comment: Thanks for those details Alaska Man!